# C++ 17 in VS causes variable (re)evaluation bug which does not exist in c++14

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017

use of a function returning an integer and (possibly) modifying a base pointer causes undesired behavior in returning the intended member of an array.

this concerns quite old legacy code; modern options using containers will solve the problem (No need to tell me, please!), but I want to point this out and ask whether the behavior is intentional under C++17, as contrasted with up to and including C++14.

The code looks like:

```
// dosomething() returns an integer.
// ArrayPointer is a class member
somememberfunction(args)
{
   ...
   return ArrayPointer[dosomething()];
}
```

The problem arises from the fact that dosomething() will change ArrayPointer and the old value of ArrayPointer is used instead of the new (under C++17, not under C++14).
The workaround is to define an intermediate variable:

```
const int index=dosomething();
return ArrayPointer[index];
```

The question is: is there an explanation (depending on the standard), or is this to be regarded as a bug, rather than just undesired behavior from my point of view?

PS: complet(er C) code, as requested, mind the non-essential parts, variable declarations omitted:

```
struct BKPRArray    // struct for applying meteocorrection
{
    double *findprarray(const char *bks)
    {
    // check earlier allocations (NR)
    for (int n = 0; n < arrays; n++)
        if (!_stricmp(this->bk[n], bks))
        {
            if (!PRarray[n]) PRarray[n] = (NUMTYPE*)calloc(FL_alloced, sizeof(NUMTYPE));
            return PRarray[n];
        }
    // combined return statement will fail under C++17 by using the old value of PRarray.
    // This MAY be caused by order of evaluation, rule 17: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order
    // allocate and prepare (preparation code omitted) a new array.
    //return PRarray[addarray(bks, defaultMeteoCorrection)];
    const auto index = addarray(bks, defaultMeteoCorrection);
    return PRarray[index];  // zet factor op +20%, want bk niet specifiek vermeld bij input.
    }
    ....
    int addarray(const char *bks, const double fact = defaultMeteoCorrection)
    {
        PRarray = (double**)realloc(PRarray, (arrays + 1) * sizeof(*PRarray));
        if (FL_alloced) PRarray[arrays] = (NUMTYPE*)calloc(FL_alloced, sizeof(NUMTYPE));
        else PRarray[arrays] = NULL;
        ...
        return arrays++;
    }
    ....
private:
    double **PRarray;   // etc.
};
```

Comment: Unclear. I'd like to see real MCVE.

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding what you are asking.  Can you show a [mcve] where it works with C++14, but fails with C++17?

Comment: I find it horrifying that anyone would modify a pointer in a function they were using to index into the memory referenced by that pointer

Answer (score 5):

Order of evaluation between `ArrayPointer` and `dosomething()` is unspefified before C++17. (So the fact that it *"works"* in C++14 is by *"chance"*).

In C++17, `ArrayPointer` should be evaluated before `dosomething()`.

see [Order of evaluation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order), Rule 17.

Comment: It still strikes me as odd that not both are (re)evaluated before executing the return (statement). The order does not appear relevant in respect to complete (evaluation).
However, I should get better at rules, for sure :)

Comment: @Jan: How many times would you want to reevaluate the expressions? Imagine something like `(a++)[i++]` (and you could have more complicated with `E1[E2]` with interdependent changes).

Comment: I may be a slow learner, but once is perfectly ok in this case. My question is why ArrayPointer was not (re)evaluated at all. That way, it appears more something related to optimization, where may be I should have used volatile.

Comment: But it is evaluated first, then index is evaluated. if you prefer, we might rewrite it to something like: `auto p = ArrayPointer; auto index = dosomething(); p[index];`. (It appears that you C++14 version does `auto index = dosomething(); auto p = ArrayPointer; p[index];` instead).